# Is there a closed form to the sum $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{2k - 1}$ ? If there is, what would that be?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I know that the sum of the first n natural numbers is $\frac{n(n + 1)}{2}$ and that the sum of the first n odd numbers is $n^2$, so I wondered what would happen if you had the ratio of the $n^{th}$ natural number to the $n^{th}$ odd number and took the summation of that.

FYI, I haven't hit college yet so my knowledge of sums is basic, I pretty much know nothing that's more advanced than the sums I've mentioned. I'm hoping for an explanation of how to find the closed form of $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{2k - 1}$ or a way to be certain that there is none.

Comment: Summing fractions is a bit trickier.  For example there is no closed form for $1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + \cdots + 1/n$, the harmonic numbers. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number

Comment: Unless you count the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) as a "closed form".

Comment: @JairTaylor It is kind of an interesting abstract question, is there a “layman’s” explanation for why a Faulhaber formula exists for all non-negative integer exponents but not negative ones?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Well, I don't see how that's any more closed form then just writing $H_n$.

Comment: @ErickWong I've wondered that as well - it would be a good separate question.  It's somewhat similar to how there's a closed form (as a rational function) for $\int x^n \, dx$ for nonnegative $n$ but not for $n = -1$.  Of course there we have closed forms for $n < -1$ as well in the integral case.  Also, if we had a simple closed form for $\sum_{k=1}^n k^{-2}$, presumably we could extract a closed form for its limit, $\pi^2/6$, as well, so that's some intuition that something less elementary is happening.

Comment: @JairTaylor Well, "closed form" is a subjective notion, which is why I wrote "Unless you count...".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with

$$\frac{k}{2k-1} = \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{2k-1}{2k-1} + \frac{1}{2k-1} \right)$$

the sum is

$$S_n = \frac{n}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2k-1}$$

As noted in the comments, the harmonic numbers are defined to be

$$H_p= \sum_{k=1}^p \frac{1}{k}.$$

Here $p=2n-1$,

so

$$\begin{aligned}
H_{2n-1} &= 1 + \frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2n-1} \\&=\left(1+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n-1} \right)\,+\, \left( \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4} + \cdots+\frac{1}{2n-2} \right)\\
&= \left( 1+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n-1}\right) \,+\,\frac{1}{2} H_{n-1}
\end{aligned} $$

and $$S_n = \frac{n}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \left(H_{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2}H_{n-1}\right).$$

Comment: Ah-- if only we could sum partial sums of odd reciprocals!

Comment: @coffeemath We could express this in terms of the digamma function, as hinted by Robert Israel.  Maybe your comment is facetious, it’s hard to tell :).

Comment: Yes, we can write the sum in terms of the digamma function, or as shown in terms of the harmonic numbers.

Comment: mjw--- My comment was meant in a joking way, but I see you've added some more relating it to other commonly defined things like the harmonic numbers. Whether these in turn are considered to have "closed form", or the digamma function etc., is I guess a matter of definition or individual taste.

Comment: @ErickWong See my above comment to mjw.

Answer (score 1):

If you make it more general
$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{ak +b}=\frac n a +\frac{b }{a^2}\left(H_{\frac{b}{a}}-H_{n+\frac{b}{a}}\right)\qquad \text{with} \quad a+b >0$$ where appear harmonic numbers.

If $n$ is large
$$S_n=\frac n a +\frac{b }{a^2} \left(H_{\frac{b}{a}}-\log (n)-\gamma
   -\frac{a+2 b}{2 a n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right
   )\right)$$